# Find all objects with broken association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models in my rails app with a has many and belongs to association.
Category has many items and Item belongs to category.

These models are associated in the normal way through a category_id column in the Item model.

I'm looking for a quick way of finding all elements in the database with broken associations.
i.e. find all categories that exist with no associated items and items that exist with no associated category.

For example, if I have an item with a category_id of 7, but the category with id 7 has been deleted then this would be considered broken.

Comment: There is a newer, Rails 3 variation and near dupe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471395/rails-3-find-condition-to-filter-broken-reference-integrity-associations

Answer (score 7):

For your example, to find items with category_id's for categories which don't exist any more:

```
Item.where('NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM categories where category.id = item.category_id)')
```

You might want to look at this as well:
A rake task to track down missing database indexes (not foreign keys though, but indexes): https://github.com/eladmeidar/rails_indexes

Answer (score 1):

A very effective way is using `find_by_sql` to let the database do the heavy lifting:

```
uncategorized_items = Item.find_by_sql("select * from items where category_id IS NULL")
```

Another way is a named scope:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :uncategorized, where(:category_id => nil) # rails 3

  # or...

  named_scope :uncategorized, :conditions => 'category_id IS NULL'
end
```

These are just a couple of ideas. I assume that once you've found these broken associations you plan to fix them, right? You might want to use `validates_associated` in both models if it's important to you that this not happen again.

You can use find_by_sql and a left outer join to find all the items in one table but not another. Here, I use a downloads table and an image_files table (I've only included the SQL):

```
SELECT d.*, d.image_file_id
from downloads as d
LEFT OUTER JOIN image_files as i 
ON i.id = d.image_file_id 
WHERE d.image_file_id IS NULL
```

Comment: That will only only find objects whose category_id is null. What I'm looking for is a way to find objects whose category_id is populated but the associated object doesn't exist. For example, if category_id is 7 but the associated category with id 7 no longer exists.

Comment: `find_by_sql` and a left outer join are your friends. Here is an example using a downloads and image_files table (edited original answer).