# Rails 3 - Find condition to filter broken Reference integrity associations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models: `TimeLog` and `Task`. `TimeLog` belongs to `Task` and `Task` has many `TimeLog`s.

In the past some `Task`s were deleted but the corresponding `TimeLog`s were not deleted (the cascade delete wasn't working). So we have some broken `TimeLog`s. They do have a `task_id` but that `task_id` does not exist anymore.

I have two questions:

1) I want to get all the `TimeLog`s from a user but filtering the broken ones.

i.e

```
TimeLog.find(:all, :conditions => ['time_log.user_id = ? and <time_log.task_id exists>])
```

2) I want to get all the broken `TimeLog`s in the console to delete them manually.

i.e.

```
TimeLog.find(:all, :conditions => [<!time_log.task_id exists>])
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add something like the following `where()` to your chain of `ActiveRelation` calls to include any orphaned `TimeLog`s:

```
.where('NOT EXISTS SELECT * FROM tasks where tasks.id = timelogs.task_id')
```

...and obviously if you remove the `NOT` you'll explicitly exclude any orphaned records.

Comment: I have other conditions. Can I apply both filtering ways (find with :conditions and where)?

Comment: You can indeed. Methods on Rails `ActiveRelation` class (e.g. `find`, `where`, `order`) themselves return an `ActiveRelation`. So you can chain these calls together to build SQL statements (e.g. `TimeLog.where(blah).where(something).order(:id)` etc). The relation is only actually evaluated to SQL and run against the DB when you try to make use of the contents with some like an `each` call. Hope that helps.

Comment: small fix for postgres (works in any sql actually): ```.where('NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tasks where tasks.id = timelogs.task_id)')
```

Answer (score 0):

A rake task to track down missing database indexes: https://github.com/eladmeidar/rails_indexes